# C++ string to binary code / binary code to string

Tags: c++, string, binary

I need to convert a string into a string with the binary code of the first string.
For the first part i used this: [Fastest way to Convert String to Binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184178/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-binary) Worked perfectly but i can't figure out a way to write it into a new string.

Here's the code i'm using so far:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < outputInformations.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << bitset<8>(outputInformations.c_str()[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
01110100011001010111001101110100011101010111001101100101011100100110111001100001011011010110010100001010011101000110010101110011011101000111000001100001011100110111001101110111011011110111001001100100
```

Is there a way to write this into a new string? So that i have a string called "binary_outputInformations" with the binary code inside it.

Comment: [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) would get you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this ?

```
  string myString = "Hello World";
  std::string binary_outputInformations;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < myString.size(); ++i)
  {
  bitset<8> b(myString.c_str()[i]);
      binary_outputInformations+= b.to_string();
  }

  std::cout<<binary_outputInformations;
```

**Output :**

`0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100`

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::ostringstream` (and hopefully C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>

std::string to_binary(const std::string& input)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for(auto c : input) {
        oss << std::bitset<8>(c);
    }
    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string outputInformations("testusername\ntestpassword");
    std::string binary_outputInformations(to_binary(outputInformations));
    std::cout << binary_outputInformations << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
01110100011001010111001101110100011101010111001101100101011100100110111001100001011011010110010100001010011101000110010101110011011101000111000001100001011100110111001101110111011011110111001001100100
```