# convert bitfield to string C++

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, converters, bit-fields

I want to convert a bitfield to a string.
Visual Studio 2008 gives an invalid null pointer exception.

Maybe it has something to do with the size of the array. it must be 8 but the output says it is 4, but why?

```
class Converter
{
public:
    string bitfieldToString (bool b_input[])
    {
        string c_conv;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(b_input) ; i++)
        {
            if(b_input[i]=false){
                c_conv.append("0");
            }
            else if (b_input[i]=true){
                c_conv.append("1");
            }
            else c_conv = "Input is not a bitfield";break;
        }
        cout<<c_conv<<" "<< sizeof(b_input)<<endl;
        return (0);
    }
};
int main(void)
{
    Converter converter;
    bool b2[8] = {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1};
    converter.bitfieldToString(b2);
    return (0);
}
```

Thank you! 
Now everything works as intended.
and sorry for that dump question. I am new to C++.

Comment: sizeof(bool[]) which should be sizeof(*bool) when I'm not completly wrong is 4 byte on a 32Bit Platform.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is using one or more `std::bitset`'s and the [`std::bitset::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string) function.

Comment: `sizeof(b_input)` This doesn't work. Pass the array size as a parameter or use `std::vector`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ string to binary code / binary code to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937892/c-string-to-binary-code-binary-code-to-string)

Comment: I do -1 since this doesn't contain any problems that are bitfield related so missleading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is because you `return (0);`. That's interpreted as a null pointer, used to initialise a `std::string` with a constructor which requires a valid pointer to a C-style string - not a null pointer.

That should be `return c_conv;`

The size mismatch is because `b_input` isn't an array. As a function parameter, `bool b_input[]` is a pointer. You can't pass an array to a function by value; and there's no way to determine the array size from the pointer alone. So `sizeof(b_input)` gives you the size of a pointer, not the array, and everything goes wrong.

There are a few options. You could pass the size as a second parameter; but that's error-prone. You could infer the size as a template argument, by taking the array by reference:

```
template <size_t size>
string bitfieldToString (bool (&b_input)[size])
```

You could use `std::array` or `std::vector`, which have handy `size()` member functions. (But be careful with `vector<bool>`, since it's a special case that doesn't always behave quite like a standard container.) Or you could use `std::bitset`, which has a handy `to_string` function that does exactly what you want.

Finally, enable your compiler's warnings - it should tell you not to use `=` where you mean `==`. And there's not much point checking for the case of a boolean being neither true nor false. You can reduce the whole loop body to

```
c_conv.append(b_input[i] ? '1' : '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a *lot* wrong in your code.

First of all, the null pointer exception comes from `return (0);` at the end of the `bitfieldToString` fuction. You have defined it to return a `string`; when you `return 0` instead, C++ thinks `0` is a `char*` pointer and will try to convert it - a `NULL`pointer - into a string, which will crash. You should probably be returning `c_conv` instead.

Second, `sizeof(b_input)` will always be the size of a `bool` pointer. On a 32-bit system it will be 4, on a 64-bit system 8. You cannot get the length of an array passed as argument with `sizeof`; you will need to add a length parameter to your function.

Third, inside your for loop, you are *assigning* to `b_input[i]` instead of comparing the values. Use `==`, not `=`.

Fourth, in the last `else` branch, you are missing braces. Essentially, the `break` will always break out of the loop after the very first iteration.