# Convert a string of binary into an ASCII string (C++)

Tags: c++, binary, ascii

I have a string variable containing 32 bits of binary. What would be the best way to convert these 4 characters (8 bits is one character) represented by the binary back into their ASCII characters?

For example, a variable contains "01110100011001010111001101110100" which should be converted back into the string "test".

Comment: One can only wonder how you ended up storing ASCII encoded text as textual binary representations of the characters. Perhaps it would be more productive to attack the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Check out [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: Just as a guess -- it sounds like a homework assignment and  `<humor>` attacking the professor is frowned on `</humor>`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are quite correct, I'm fairly new to C++ and only just discovered std::bitset. I knew my method felt very wrong indeed!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative if you're using C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::string data = "01110100011001010111001101110100";
    std::stringstream sstream(data);
    std::string output;
    while(sstream.good())
    {
        std::bitset<8> bits;
        sstream >> bits;
        char c = char(bits.to_ulong());
        output += c;
    }

    std::cout << output;

   return 0;
}
```

Note that bitset is part of C++11.

Also note that if data is not well formed, the result will be silently truncated when sstream.good() returns false.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, I have just discovered std::bitset so I'll work on a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this with method. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string BinaryStringToText(string binaryString) {
    string text = "";
    stringstream sstream(binaryString);
    while (sstream.good())
    {
        bitset<8> bits;
        sstream >> bits;
        text += char(bits.to_ulong());
    }
    return text;
}

int main()
{
    string binaryString = "0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100";
    cout << "Binary string: " << binaryString << "!\n";
    cout << "Result binary string to text: " << BinaryStringToText(binaryString) << "!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

result code:

```
Binary string: 0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100!                                                                                                  
Result binary string to text: Hello World!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;  

int main()
try
{

   string myString = "Hello World"; // string object

   vector<bitset<8>> us;           // string to binary array of each characater

   for (int i = 0; i < myString.size(); ++i)
   {
        // After convert string to binary, push back of the array
        us.push_back(bitset<8>(myString[i]));
   }

   string c;  // binary to string object

   for (int i = 0; i < us.size(); ++i)
    {
        // the function 'to_ulong' returns
        // integer value with the same bit representation as the bitset object.
        c += char(us[i].to_ulong());
    }

    cout << c;

}
catch (exception& e)
{
    cerr << "the error is : " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

output : Hello World

[Fastest way to Convert String to Binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184178/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-binary)

To convert string to binary, I referred to the answer above link.

[Convert a string of binary into an ASCII string (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344257/convert-a-string-of-binary-into-an-ascii-string-c)

To convert binary to string, I referred to the answer above link, the answer of Dale Wilson.

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt:

```
std::string str2bits(const std::string_view &str, bool big_endian = false)
{
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(str.size() * 8);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        const uint8_t ord = uint8_t(str[i]);
        for (int bitnum = (big_endian ? 0 : 7);; (big_endian ? (++bitnum) : (--bitnum)))
        {
            if ((big_endian && bitnum >= 8) || (!big_endian && bitnum < 0))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (ord & (1 << bitnum))
            {
                ret += "1";
            }
            else
            {
                ret += "0";
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

str2bits("test") ==> 01110100011001010111001101110100

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be this, which is more flexible:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

std::string BinaryTextToASCIIText(const std::string& binaryText, const unsigned int blockSize = 8, const unsigned int separatorLength = 1)
{
    std::string text(""), block;
    unsigned int separatorBlockStartIndex = blockSize;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < binaryText.length(); i++)
    {
        if (i == separatorBlockStartIndex)
        {
            i += separatorLength;
            separatorBlockStartIndex += blockSize + separatorLength;
        }
        
        block += binaryText[i];

        if (block.length() == 8)
        {
            char binaryTextToASCIIChar = 0;
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < block.length(); j++)
            {
                if (block[j] == '1')
                {
                    binaryTextToASCIIChar += pow(2, block.length() - j - 1);
                }
            }

            block.clear();
            text += binaryTextToASCIIChar;
        }
    }

    return text;
}

int main()
{
    //if you have your binary text in blocks of 32 bits and the blocks have been separated with " " (the separator can be any kind of ascii character and any length) you can use the function like this:
    std::cout << BinaryTextToASCIIText("01110100011001010111001101110100", 32, 1) << std::endl;
    //here is an example of blocks of 32 bits and the "0101111011010" (13 characters long) separator
    std::cout << BinaryTextToASCIIText("010101000110100001101001011100110101111011010001000000110100101110011001000000101111011010011000010010000001110100011001010101111011010011100110111010000100001", 32, 13);

    return 0;
}
```

The method can be much more useful, of course.. can be improved for sure, but works pretty good.