# Equivalent of Java's String.getBytes() in C++?

Tags: java, c++, linux, string, encryption

I need to implement a decrypt method in c++ from a Java encrypted string passed to me from a server.
The Java encrypted method is this:

```
 public String crypt (String strMsg)throws CryptUtilException{
    byte bytePosition;
    int intMsgLen = strMsg.length();
    int intKeyLen = strKey.length();
    byte[] aByteMsg = strMsg.getBytes();
    byte[] aByteOutMsg = new byte[intMsgLen];

    if (intMsgLen==0) {
        throw new CryptUtilException("In String is null.");
    } else{
        for (int i=0; i<intMsgLen; i++) {
            bytePosition = (byte) (i%intKeyLen);
            aByteOutMsg[i] = (byte)((aByteMsg[i] - iCharOffSet) + (byte) strKey.charAt(bytePosition) + bytePosition);
            if (aByteOutMsg [i] < 0) aByteOutMsg [i] = (byte) (aByteOutMsg [i] + 128);
        }

        String strOutMsg = new String (aByteOutMsg);
        return strOutMsg;
    }
}
```

My work colleague use that code for encrypt and the following code for decrypt a string and suggest my to replicate this Java code into my C++ project:

```
public String decrypt (String strMsg)throws CryptUtilException{
    byte bytePosition;
    int intMsgLen = strMsg.length();
    int intKeyLen = strKey.length();
    byte[] aByteMsg = strMsg.getBytes();
    byte[] aByteOutMsg = new byte[intMsgLen];

    if (intMsgLen==0) {
        throw new CryptUtilException("In String is null.");
    } else{
        for (int i=0; i<intMsgLen; i++) {
            bytePosition = (byte) (i%intKeyLen);
            aByteOutMsg[i] = (byte)((aByteMsg[i] + iCharOffSet) - (byte) strKey.charAt(bytePosition) - bytePosition);
            if (aByteOutMsg [i] < 0) aByteOutMsg [i] = (byte) (aByteOutMsg [i] + 128);
        }

        String strOutMsg = new String (aByteOutMsg);
        return strOutMsg;
    }
}
```

I have a lot of difficulty doing it because I don't find a valid method for replicate the Java getBytes() method.
In addition, I have a very old version of C++ and for this I can't use the "byte" or the "wstring_convert" method and I'm not working on windows OS.

Comment: You could use `operator[]` with the string to get a character at a given position.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505021/get-bytes-from-stdstring-in-c

Comment: C++ is not Java. In C++, a `std::string`'s contents are accessed directly as if it was a container, since `std::string` implements the same methods as random access containers. So: access the bytes in the string as if you were to access the contents of a `std::vector`. If one had an itch to extract the contents of a string into a `std::vector` anyway, one would simply construct the `std::vector` using the overloaded constructor that takes a beginning and ending sequence iterator, and then pass in `std::string`'s `begin()` and `end()`. But that would not really accomplish much.

Comment: Put it another way your `aByteMsg` and `aByteOutMsg` variables are unnecessary in the C++ version. Just read and write 'bytes' directly from the string. Also note C++ strings are mutable, unlike Java.

Answer (score 0):

`char/unsigned char` types are an equivalent of `byte` in Java or other languages.

`std::string` has method `c_str()`, which returns `char*` with the length of `std::string::size()`. `char*`, being a c-string, can be considered as a full and complete binary representation of the underlying string.

Basically,

```
std::string s;

const char* s_data = s.c_str();
// do what you want with s_data
```

If all you want is an access to characters, using operator[] is enough:

```
char p = s[i]; // process that p as you want!
```

Information, provided [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), should be enough for any kind of interaction with strings.

Comment: In C++, char, signed char, and unsigned char are 3 distinct types - the closest to Java's (signed) byte would normally by 'signed char', not 'char' or 'unsigned char'.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score -3):

The closes C++ equivalent of Java `byte[]` is [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte). You can construct it from `std::string strMsg` like:

```cpp
std::vector<std::byte> bytes(strMsg.begin(), strMsg.end());
```

Comment: std::byte is c++17-specific.

Comment: @LeontyevGeorgiy so? AFAIR it is also in c++20

Comment: >> I have a very old version of C++

This.